# Multiple-replace in python

Tags: python

I do the following for replacing.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("input.txt",inplace=1):
     line = line.replace("A","A'")
     print line,
```

But I want to do it many replaces.

Replace A with A' , B with BB, C with CX, D with KK, etc.

I can of course do this by repeating the above code many times.

But I guess that will consume a lot of time especially when input.txt is large.

How can I do this elegantly?

**Emphasis added**

My input is not just a str ABCD.

I need to use input.txt as input and I want to replace every occurrences of A in input.txt to A', every occurrences in input.txt of B to BB, every occurrences of C in input.txt to CX, every occurrences of D in input.txt to KK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a mapping dictionary:

```
>>> map_dict = {'A':"A'", 'B':'BB', 'C':'CX', 'D':'KK'}
>>> strs = 'ABCDEF'
>>> ''.join(map_dict.get(c,c) for c in strs)
"A'BBCXKKEF"
```

In Python3 use `str.translate` instead of `str.join`:

```
>>> map_dict = {ord('A'):"A'", ord('B'):'BB', ord('C'):'CX', ord('D'):'KK'}
>>> strs = 'ABCDEF'
>>> strs.translate(map_dict)
"A'BBCXKKEF"
```

Comment: Is it using strs as input? I need to use input.txt as input and I want to replace every occurrences of A in input.txt to A', every occurrences in input.txt of B to BB, every occurrences of C in input.txt to CX, every occurrences of D in input.txt to KK.

Comment: @user2604484 Then simply use the text read from input.txt instead of `strs`.

Comment: Hmm I am sorry but I just started to learn python, could you edit the codes in the answer to write the full changes needed including "reading from input.txt"?

Comment: @user2604484 Have you tried: `line = ''.join(map_dict.get(c,c) for c in line)`  ?

Comment: Thank you! However I got one question. You wrote {'A':"A'", 'B':'BB', 'C':'CX', 'D':'KK'}  Here, what replaces A is wrapped by " and ", but what replaces B, C, D are wrapped by ' and '. Why? Should the first one be always " instead of ' ?

Comment: And what if I want to replace A with ' or replace B with "? {'A':'''} or {'B':"""} seems to be causing errors. Just do {'A':"'"} and {'B':'"'} ?

Comment: @user2604484 You can't use double quotes inside double quotes without escaping the, and same thing applies to single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> replace_map = {
...   'A': "A'",
...   'B': 'BB',
...   'C': 'CX',
...   'D': 'KK',
...   'EFG': '.',
... }
>>> pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, replace_map))
>>> re.sub(pattern, lambda m: replace_map[m.group()], 'ABCDEFG')
"A'BBCXKK."
```